# Powershell Hashtable: Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "2"

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I don't have an idea why this code does throw the exceptions:

```
$args_path = ".\publish_args.config"
$args=$null
$args=@{}
$args.Add("K", "V") # this line works as excpected
Get-Content -Path $args_path | ForEach-Object {    
    $val = $_ -replace "\\", "\\" 
    $var = $val.Split('=')  
    Write-Host $var[0] = $var[1] # sample output: backup_folder = "C:\\temp\\test\\W\\Backup"
    $args.Add($var[0], $var[1]) #throws the exception "Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "2"."
}

foreach($key in $args.Keys){
    Write-Host $key = $args[$key]
}
```

I'm feeling really stupid, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use `$args` for the variable name because it is an [Automatic Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6#args) in PowerShell

Comment: Hell...thanks, @Theo this resolved the issue.